Difference between pre-algebra and early algebra in primary school teacher education
The context here is a course for primary school teachers who want to get a qualification for teaching mathematics. "Algebra" does not therefore mean university level or proof-based algebra. The course is in English and many from the target audience have a background in USA or Great Britain.
Given this, how should I understand the two terms in the title? What are they likely to mean and is there some conceptual or otherwise clear line to draw between them?
The book we are using as the main literature on the course does not use these precise terms, at least not a lot. (They might be mentioned somewhere in there, who knows.) The book is

VAN DE WALLE, John A.; KARP, Karen S.; BAY-WILLIAMS, Jennifer M. Elementary and middle school mathematics: Teaching developmentally. Pearson. 2022.

I have earlier met the idea of introducing algebra early to young pupils and this is an idea I associate to the phrase "early algebra". However, I do not know if the phrase also has some jargon meaning in the anglosphere educational systems, hence the question.
The related question What topics are considered to be part of pre-algebra? seems to have a broader or less clearly defined scope, and at least some of the answers assume more of a university or high school perspective, and thus a new question seems appropriate.

Of course it's hard to know exactly someone else means, but I'll do my best.
I think it is "likely" (your request) that they are talking about solving degree one x equations:
5x+3=2x-5 or that sort of thing.
That's the core content in American "pre-algebra" (8th grade, 13 year olds)
The core content of American algebra (9th grade, 14 year olds) is in order
(a) Lines (i.e. x and y) and slope meaning, intercepts, and the various traditional equations (two point, y=mx+b, etc.)
(b) Solving simultaneous linear equations: 2 eqn and two unknowns, 3 eqns and 3 unknowns
(c) Quadratic equation (to include completing the square, for strong kids)
Possibly "early algebra" (not a typical term) might mean (a) above.
It's also possible--would be good to see the context, whole sentences of description--that they are using the two terms synonymously, not as different topics.  In that case, it would just be pre-algebra as I described.
